# Can't open VB editor in EXCEL 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I used to be able to open the VB editor in EXCEL, but suddenly I can't.  I was in compatibility mode but have reset to normal mode.  Other Workbook now have the same problem.

Comment: Have you try to press Alt-F11 ?

Comment: Do you try any methods to troubelshoot this problem first? At least please try to repair Office first: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b

Comment: Repair online fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like corruption. If reinstalling Office doesn't help, try deleting the VBA key in the registry (which is left unchanged by (re)installation) ...

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA

If you delete this key, a clean copy should be created from built-in defaults when you open the VBE.

found answer in google